# Mule ESB Web service mapping

Tags: soap, cxf, transform, mule, forward

I'm a newbie trying to implement a simple web service mapping in Mule.

Basically, the flow should receive a Soap request ("ExampleWS1"), marshall it to a bean, map this bean to another, and send it to another service. In return, the same mapping process should be performed until a Soap response is given back to caller.

With a trick I could forward the request in the form of an object ("CriteriaWS1") and everything goes fine until returning the response object ("PersonWS1"), but I get the following exception:

com.acme.example.ws1.beans.PersonWS1 cannot be cast to com.acme.example.ws1.beans.CriteriaWS1

The trick was to publish ExampleWS1 with this contract, allowing it to forward Criteria1, but I suppose that now this is blocking response:

public CriteriaWS1 search(@WebParam(name="criteria") CriteriaWS1 criteria)

I suppose that this service should return PersonWS1, but how to forward the object CriteriaWS1?
I've tried with every linear combination of: cxf:proxy-service, pattern:web-proxy-service, transformer-refs, responseTransformer-refs... but no way.
Maybe I must use Mule API to do something like this from inside search(-) method:

```
output = muleClient.send("vm://nextFlowPiece", input);
```

Here is the configuration I used. I'm using Mule 3.2.1 under Mule IDE.

Any help will be appreciated, so many thanks in advance.

Gabriele

```
<flow name="Demo_WS_2_WS_RequestReply_1">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:4006/services/ExampleWS1" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.acme.example.ws1.ExampleWS1"/>
    <component>
        <singleton-object class="com.acme.example.ws1.ExampleWS1" />
    </component>
    <custom-transformer name="WS1WS2TransformerIn" class="com.acme.example.WS1WS2TransformerLegacy"/> 

    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="vm1_acq" responseTimeout="1000" />
    <custom-transformer name="WS2WS1TransformerOut" class="com.acme.example.WS2WS1TransformerLegacy"/> 
</flow>
<flow name="Demo_WS_2_WS_RequestReply_2">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="vm1_acq" responseTimeout="1000" />
    <cxf:jaxws-client 
             clientClass="com.acme.example.ws2.ExampleWS2Service" 
             port="ExampleWS2Port"
             wsdlLocation="classpath:ExampleWS2.wsdl" 
             operation="search"/>
    <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:4003/services/ExampleWS2"/>
</flow>
```

(PS: I attach some code as requested by David, with both solutions I implemented. The first one is the less tricky so I'll go with that.)

1) forward request with MuleClient from within web service class, after it has been unmarshalled by CXF:

`@WebMethod`

```
public PersonWS1 search(@WebParam(name="criteria") CriteriaWS1 criteria) {
    ...
        MuleMessage resultMessage = muleContext.getClient().process("vm://VM_FROM_INBOUND", MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE, new DefaultMuleMessage(criteria, muleContext));
        result = (PersonWS1)resultMessage.getPayload();
    ...
    return result;
}
```

2) declare web method to return an "Object", then chain request as the example above, but annotating method to let JABX bind the response the correct way:

`@WebResult(name = "personWS1")`

```
public Object search(@WebParam(name = "criteria") CriteriaWS1 criteria) {
    return criteria;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could help but it's very hard by just glancing at the config. What component is throwing the class cast exception you're experiencing? Why isn't WS2WS1TransformerOut able to rectify the situation by building the excepted object type? Also bear in mind cxf elements add contextual data in message properties: you're maybe messing with this without noticing. Finally: I'd personally go for composition instead of chaining, ie have com.acme.example.ws1.ExampleWS1 call vm://vm1_acq with the MuleClient.

Comment: Thank you very much David.
Now both solutions work, let me expose them as they could be useful to someone:
1) forward request with MuleClient from within web service class, after it has been unmarshalled by CXF
2) declare web method to return an "Object", then chain request as the example above, but annotating method to let JABX bind the response the correct way

Thank you again for your precious help.

Gabriele